# How to create a custom Hooks in reactjs hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to create a custom Hooks for handling input HTTP request from any component by  simply calling the useCustomHooks but its getting failed and error is

Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

All i made is a handler that triggers http request custom component method

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

const useHttpReqHandler = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState();

    const apiMethod = async ({url , data , method}) => {
        let options = {
            method,
            url,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            data
        };
        let response = await axios(options);
        const UpdatedData = await response.data;
        console.log(UpdatedData)
        setResult(UpdatedData);
    }

    return [result, apiMethod];
};

export default useHttpReqHandler;
```

Now i can use this hook in my code and on any event handler just call callAPI returned from the hook like this

```
const MyFunc = () => {
    const [apiResult, apiMethod] = useHttpReqHandler();


    const captchValidation = () => {
        const x = result.toString();;
        const y = inputValue.toString();;
        if ( x === y) {
            apiMethod({url: 'some url here', data: {"email": email}, method: 'post'});
             alert("success")
        }
        else {
             alert("fail")
        }

    }
```

Is is a correct approch ? as i am beginner in Reactjs

Comment: You're calling `await` inside `useEffect`, but `useEffect` is not async

Comment: Hi @HermitCrab  is this a right approach? i made an edit to my post, but will run infinite times

Comment: There are many mistakes in your custom hook, I can work on it and post a working version if you want

Comment: Hi @HermitCrab  if you can it will be useful thanks if you can do this for me as i have started react with from last 2 weeks only

Comment: Hi @HermitCrab if you can guide me it will so much helpful

Comment: Almost but apiMethod won't return anything, it's just apiResult that will be updated

Comment: But apiMethod will call the axios method call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212181/discussion-between-hermitcrab-and-akhi21).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working version:

**useHttpReqHandler.jsx**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

const useHttpReqHandler = () => {
    const [apiResult, setApiResult] = useState();

    const apiMethod = async ({url , data , method}) => {
        let options = {
            method,
            url,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            data
        };
        let response = await axios(options);
        let responseOK = response && response.status === 200 && response.statusText === 'OK';
        if (responseOK) {
            const data = await response.data;
            console.log(data)
            setApiResult(data);
        }
    }

    return [apiResult, apiMethod];
};

export default useHttpReqHandler;
```

What's important here:

- await is called inside an async function (apiMethod)
- The result is stored in a local state (apiResult)
- The function returns an array [apiResult, apiMethod]

**How to use it:**

```
const [apiResult, apiMethod] = useHttpReqHandler();
apiMethod({url: 'some url here', data: {"email": email}, method: 'post'});
```

Render the result:

```
return {apiResult};
```

Comment: Hi @HermitCrab, I am not able to get how to use it? i just made an edit to the question can i use in this way ? please do look

Comment: `useHttpReqHandler` must return an array. First element is a state variable (apiResult) that will be updated after a successful axios call, second element is a function to call (apiMethod)

Comment: As i had made an edit in question is that the right approach?

Comment: Hi @HermitCrab how can I add sppiner in your code ? if you got a time please do add in your code

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is better to use .then with Axios. and try to create for each method different functions "Get/Post...", why because in the GET method you need to useEffect, but it can not be the same case in POST method. in GET method `useHttpReqHandler.js`

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

// GET DATA
const useHttpReqHandler = (url) => {
  const [httpData, setHttpData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((axiosData) => {
        // Axios DATA object

        setHttpData(axiosData.data);
        // you can check what is in the object by console.log(axiosData);
        // also you can change the state, call functions...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return httpData;
};
export default useHttpReqHandler;
```

in your `main file`

```
import useHttpReqHandler from "...."
const MyFunc = () => {
       const getData = useHttpReqHandler("URL");

   return (
      <div>
...
</div>
   )
}
```

I hope it helps

the same thing will be with POSt, PUT, DELETE ... you will create functions for each method that will handle the Http req

Comment: hi @Ahmed for post request how will i send post req parameter in this way  ``` axios.post(url ,data)```

Comment: you can do it like this axios.post(`https:api.com/${parameter}`,yourData);